# Add character on twig with replace

Tags: twig

I want to add character like ** with replace in twig.

```
 {% if faq.customer_username|length > 2 %}
    <span class="card-user colorBlack fz12"> 
        {{faq.customer_username|replace({(faq.customer_username|last):'**'}) }}
    </span>
 {% else %}
    <span class="card-user colorBlack fz12">
  {{ faq.customer_username|replace({(faq.customer_username): faq.customer_username + '**'}) }}
   </span>
{% endif %}
```

But it's not work please help me thank so much

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the expected output? Concatenation in `twig` is done with `~` and not `+`

Comment: Yeah thanks so much. It work with ~. I'm new in twig.